# How to stop C++ ODBC queries consuming lots of memory

Tags: c++, database, qt, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to write some code that opens up an access database (accdb). It then reads and writes a lot of data. As it does so the memory usage of the application consumes a large amount of memory (up to 3GB). I have narrowed the problem down to the actual SQL queries. It seems that QSqlDatabase, QSqlRecord or the ODBC driver are consuming large amounts of data and not releasing it.

I'm opening the database with a Qt class QSqlDatabase. This takes a connection string to the ODBC driver and a filename of the .accdb file.

```
bool AccessDatabase::openAccdb(const QString& filename, const QString& password)
{
bool result = false;

    if (QFileInfo(filename).exists())
    {
        bool ok = QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QODBC");
        if (!ok)
        {
            QString ErrorMsg = "No ODBC driver available!";
            return false;
        }
    
        *mDatabase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
        mDatabase->setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + filename + ";");
        if (mDatabase->open())
        {
            result = true;
            mLastError = "";
        }
        else
        {
            mLastError = "Failed to open database. Have you set up the ODBC DSN entry? - " + mDatabase->lastError().text();
            assert(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mLastError = "Database does not exist";
    }
    
    return (result);
}
```

Then every read and write request uses an SQL statement to perform the operation.

```
AccessDatabase::SqlRecordList AccessDatabase::query(const QString& queryStatement)
{
QMutexLocker locker(mDatabaseMutex);
SqlRecordList result;
QSqlQuery* qSQLQuery = new QSqlQuery(\*mDatabase);

    auto queryStr = queryStatement;
    
    // Are we dealing with a a database read?
    auto selectLen = strlen("SELECT");
    if (queryStr.left(selectLen).toUpper() == "SELECT")
    {
        exec(qSQLQuery, queryStr);
        while (qSQLQuery->next())
        {
            QSqlRecord record = qSQLQuery->record();
            SqlRecord resultRecord;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < record.count(); ++i)
            {
                resultRecord.setField(record.fieldName(i), qSQLQuery->value(i).toString());
            } // ENDFOR
            result.push_back(resultRecord);
        } // ENDWHILE
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a write operation. Just execute it. There are no results.
        exec(qSQLQuery, queryStr);
    }
    
    if (qSQLQuery->isActive())
    {
        qSQLQuery->finish();
        qSQLQuery->clear();
    }
    else
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    delete qSQLQuery;
    return result;
}
```

It may be that opening and closing the database all the time will release the memory, but I'd rather not do that.

I am aware that there are 'prepare' and 'bindValue' calls that I could use instead of a formatted QString, but I can't believe that they are more efficient unless the same query is being used multiple times. It is on my todo list, but there are rather a lot of code changes to make and if they have no effect then I'd be wasting my time.

I'm thinking that perhaps the ODBC driver or the Qt library is storing the queries or the result to make subsequent call more efficient.

How can I tell them to release the memory?

I am deleting the query and using query.finish() and query.clean() and deleting the QSqlRecord structure when I have finished with them but still the memory usage escalates.

I've tried using different ODBC drivers, but I cant get them to work.

Comment: QSqlQuery* qSQLQuery = new QSqlQuery(\\*mDatabase); looks strange: what's with "\\*mDatabase)", why new QSqlQuery instead of just stack-allocated one?

Another suspicious (on first glance) part is exec(qSQLQuery, queryStr); -- what is this exec()? Why is it not qSQLQuery->exec(queryStr); ? Doesn't it, like QSqlDatabase::exec, return another qSQLQuery?

Comment: The heap allocation was someone's suggestion. The exec call is essentially qSQLQuery->exec with some error reporting.

Comment: void AccessDatabase::exec(QSqlQuery* qSQLQuery, const QString& queryString)
{
    mLastError = "";
    if (!qSQLQuery->exec(queryString))
    {
        auto error = qSQLQuery->lastError();
        if (error.type() != QSqlError::NoError)
        {
            mLastError = "Query failed - " + error.text() + "\nSQL = " + queryString;
            assert(false);
        }
    }
}

Comment: OK, still can't reproduce. Although, judging from QMutexLocker locker(mDatabaseMutex); you are sharing a connection across threads, which is forbidden, but I couldn't make it retain memory allocated in qSQLQuery anyway.

Generally, if you want to use threads, you have to use named connections: in QSqlDatabase::addDatabase you use a string with the thread-unique name for second argument, and then obtain connections with calls like db= QSqlDatabase::database("Conn1");  QSqlQuery query(db);

Comment: Since you only next() here, you can call qSQLQuery.setForwardOnly(true); this usually prevents memory hogging, QSqlQuery usually just not demands any significant amount of memory in this mode. 

But this requires discipline, you should do everything by the book: no pointers to database, query or other sql classes, no members of these classes or other savings, etc. Just {db= QSqlDatabase::database("Conn1"); QSqlQuery query(db); query.setForwardOnly(true); (it must be set immediately after the definition of your query) query.exec(); if(query.IsSelect) {while(query.next()){//}else{}}

Comment: Sorry, It looks like the leak is elsewhere. Thanks for all the help Mike. Your comments were very helpful. I will certainly use your suggestions, mod my database class and then look to the code that uses the database data, which I now think is the source of the leak.